# MVC4 Controller returning wrong url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Thank you in advance, this is the issue:  I have this  form that has an Action to Main Controller specifically to Index.  The first time  goes makes the query and return

```
"http://localhost:59761/Main/Index"
```

but when i make a second  drop down selection it's goes and return

```
"http://localhost:59761/Main/Main/Index"
```

(returning controller twice). Basically what i want is to return the index.

here is the view:

> ```
> <form  method="post" action="Main/Index">
>      <select name="week"  id="week">
>             <option value=1>Week 1</option>
>             <option value=2>Week 2</option>
>             <option value=3>Week 3</option>
>             <option value=4>Week 4</option>
>             <option value=5>Week 5</option>
>      </select>  
>   <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search"/>     
>   </form>
> ```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? week )
    {
        if (week != null)
        {
            var quest = (from q in db.weekly_games
                         where q.week_um == week
                         select q).ToList();
            return View(quest);
        }

        return View(db.weekly_games.ToList());

    }
```

here is the RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Replace `action="Main/Index"` with `action="@Href("~/Main/Index")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Html.Beginform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590(v=vs.118).aspx) html helper method instead of hard coding the action value in your form. It will render the correct value for your form's `action` property.'

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Main"))
{
     <select name="week"  id="week">
            <option value=1>Week 1</option>
            <option value=2>Week 2</option>
            <option value=3>Week 3</option>
            <option value=4>Week 4</option>
            <option value=5>Week 5</option>
     </select>  
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search"/>     
}
```